# Restrict creating View from a Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I want to create a controller and that is only used to do asynchronous call (using jquery). I dont want to use that controller and create a View from that. Is there a way available to restrict creating View from that controller?

Comment: Who could be restricted except you? Users can't create views from controllers.

Comment: User should not be allowed create view from that.

Comment: Pls tell me  how application users can create a form that could be returned from a controller?

Comment: Sorry, not application users, I mean developers...

Comment: If developers need to  return a view they  just will  change the restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a controller class, there is no set rule that it must come with its own view. Also, you might be needing `webapi` instead of regular `controller`